# Why is the $ sign used in this bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm looking on Fedora sysV init script example and it goes like this:

```
#...some code
 start() {
    [ -x $exec ] || exit 5
    [ -f $config ] || exit 6
    echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
    # if not running, start it up here, usually something like "daemon $exec"
    retval=$?
    echo
    [ $retval -eq 0 ] && touch $lockfile
    return $retval
}
#...some more code....
```

What is the reason for first dollar sign in this line, because it seems that script will work perfectly fine without it - will it not?

```
echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
```

Answer (score 6):

`$"..."` is an extension that allows you to [use gettext i18n in bash scripts](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#i18nl10n).

Comment: Could you link to documentation or at least a source for this?

Comment: @jtbandes: I'm looking for some, but they're hard to find.

Comment: hmm. here's an example here - but they use parenthesys: http://docs.unity-linux.org/I18n_Support_and_Shell_Scripts

Comment: @Andre: That's because that's a completely different mechanism.

Comment: [Here it is](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Major-Differences-From-The-Bourne-Shell); it's the 10th bullet item, which links [to this](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Locale-Translation).